# spyder ide not launching

Tags: ide, spyder

Just downloaded Syder 3 IDE but the Spyder IDE doesn't launch it gets stuck on loading editor and then nothing happens. [image]

Comment: Please open an Anaconda prompt, run there `spyder --show-console` and update your question with the errors shown there.

Comment: did spyder --show-console and it does nothing but shows same problem